# Dialogbox not showing and app crashes

Tags: java, android, dialog

I want to show dialogbox containing radio buttons which are added dynamically and then when a user selects a radio button and press OK button, it should return the name of that radio button.
I have made the app but the app crashes when I try to run it on my mobile? I am following this tutorial and then utilizing it for my work. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659766/Android-Custom-DialogBox.

**What is the error in the code that is causing the app to crash?**

*MainActivity.java*

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String countryName[] = { "India", "Pakistan", "China", "Nepal", "Bangladesh" };
TextView textDialog;
RadioGroup rg;
Button btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textDialog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    showCustomDialog(textDialog);
}

public void showCustomDialog(final TextView _textDialog) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

    final RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[countryName.length];
    rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
    for (int i = 0; i < countryName.length; i++) {
        rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        rg.addView(rb[i]);
        rb[i].setText(countryName[i]);
    }

    Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);    
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String text = "";

            if(rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please select Gender", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                int selectedId = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);
                text = selectedRadioButton.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedRadioButton.getText().toString()+" is selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            _textDialog.setText(text);
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
}
}
```

*main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RadioGroup  
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </RadioGroup>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

## Logcat

```
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): Process: com.example.dialogbox, PID: 14823
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dialogbox/com.example.dialogbox.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2200)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1200)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5105)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:792)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:608)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.example.dialogbox.MainActivity.showCustomDialog(MainActivity.java:42)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at com.example.dialogbox.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5275)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2164)
05-21 05:48:06.291: E/AndroidRuntime(14823):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the exception that causes the crash?

Comment: @TimoSta this is the logcat snapshot 
http://www.mediafire.com/convkey/59c7/9t4c5mycmyojt3qzg.jpg

Comment: Please copy the complete stack trace of the `NullPointerException` into your question.

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/view/341brrg5o0lsubp/log.txt

Comment: Please add this to your question.

Comment: Which line is line 42 of MainActivity.java?

Comment: rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL); //line 42
showCustomDialog(textDialog);        //line 28

Comment: The problem is with radio group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes and it will work for sure

i. **Remove** `RadioGroup rg;` and `Button btn;` before onCreate()

ii. **Replace** `rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);`with `final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)dialog.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);`

iii. **Remove** `btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);`

iv. **Replace** `Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);` with `Button button = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);`

v. In else, **Replace** `RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)findViewById(selectedId);` with `RadioButton selectedRadioButton = (RadioButton)dialog.findViewById(selectedId);`

Answer (score 0):

`rg` is null in this line:

```
rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
```

This means that `findViewById()` cannot find the id you passed when you set it in this line:

```
rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radio_group);
```

If `findViewById()` does not find the specified id, it returns `null` as you can read [in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#findViewById(int)).

This is because `R.id.radio_group` is located in activity `activity_main`, you however inflated `main`:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Consequently, your `R.id.radio_group` can't possibly found at this point.

Comment: By moving all the screen elements to one activity XML file and inflating this activity. You cannot work with screen elements that you defined in a different activity than your current one.

Comment: When I define all the elements in one activity.xml, still it does not work

Comment: I ve done, Thanks for your time and being so nice, I really appreciate it :)